# Working & debugging remotely with VS code & jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vscode-remote

I have recently started working with VS-Code & Python Jupyter Notebook remotely using SSH and it was great until now. Almost had the experience of working directly on the server as I was able to execute and debug the notebook cells.

As I swapped between servers (containers / VDIs with the same file system), something might have happened to the remote extensions. The debugging had stopped working. I click on the debug button for a notebook cell, but the debug toolbar does not reach the breakpoint. The step option does not appear on the debugging screen.

Any suggestions on how to analyze/solve this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looking on the vscode various logs (I think it was the python log) I found an exception occurs when I tried to step a single line. Searching further on the network I found this:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8803

In short downgrading my `ipykernel` package from 6.8.0 to 6.7.0 did the trick and solved my problem.